# Calculated formula for sharepoint list to return "expired"

Tags: sharepoint

The formula I am using is:

```
=IF((DATEDIF(Todaycalc,[TERMINATION DATE],"d"))<0,"Expired","")
```

but while it calculates for the NO, I am getting a #NUM error for the part I want to return as "expired". the calculated field is set to text.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the `TodayCalc` item in your `DATEDIF` function is.  If this is a column then it needs to be inside brackets `[Todaycalc]`.  If you are trying to use the `TODAY` formula to return the current date, you cannot use this (or `ME`) in Calculated Columns.

There is a trick to getting this to "work" where you use a column named Today, use it in the formula then delete it.  But it is a silly trick since it still only calculates when an item is created/modified.  You might as well use the [Modified column](http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2008/08/14/calculated-columns-the-useless-today-trick/).

Answer (score 1):

As @thisChrisKent has said you can't use the [Today] trick without some serious workarounds - it just [doesn't work as you would expect it too](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2008/11/truth-about-using-today-in-calculated-columns/).

You've a couple of options for doing this sort of dynamic view.

- Convert the List View Web Part (LVWP) to a [Data View Web Part (DVWP)](http://www.sharepoint-tips.com/2007/05/sharepoint-designer-article-2-creating.html) and add formatting via SharePoint designer and/or XSLT/JavaScript
- Add [javascript in a Content Editor Web Part to apply the formatting](http://sp2010.pathtosharepoint.com/Portfolio/Pages/Countdown.aspx) - Christophe is a great source for this sort of stuff which you could adapt for your needs.
- 3rd party products and custom calcualted columns - such as [Highlighter](http://www.pentalogic.net/sharepoint-products/highlighter), [Follow-Up](http://www.artfulbits.com/products/sharepoint/follow-up.aspx), [Corus Works](http://community.corasworks.net/AppsHome.aspx?CWFrameSource=FrameAppDetail.aspx?C=26&RID=76) and others
  *(disclaimer - first link is from my own company)*

Comment: +1 for providing a real solution. I'm not in England, but let me know if you ever need an American Teleworker :)